# Java method prints something else

Tags: java, methods, printing, println

I´m writting some methods on Java for Fraction operations using instances as parameters, but for some reason I dont get, when I try to print the result from another class it prints something like "(PackageName).(ClassName)@1497b7b1".
This only happens with "Suma", "Resta", "División", "Multiplicación" methods.
Here's the code so you can understand better:

```
package fracciones;

public class Fraction {

    private int Numerador;
    private int Denominador;

    public Fraction() {
        Numerador = 0;
        Denominador = 1;
    }

    public Fraction(int Num, int Den) {
        Numerador = Num;
        Denominador = Den;
    }

    public int getNumerador() {
        return Numerador;
    }

    public int getDenominador() {
        return Denominador;
    }

    public Fraction Suma(Fraction Suma) {
        int Num = Suma.getNumerador();
        int Den = Suma.getDenominador();

        Fraction c = new Fraction();

        c.Numerador = Numerador * Den + Denominador * Num;
        c.Denominador = Denominador * Den;
        return c;
    }

    public Fraction Resta(Fraction Resta) {
        int Num = Resta.getNumerador();
        int Den = Resta.getDenominador();

        Fraction c = new Fraction();

        c.Numerador = Numerador * Den - Num * Denominador;
        c.Denominador = Denominador * Den;
        return c;
    }

    public Fraction Multiplicación(Fraction Multiplicación) {
        int Num = Multiplicación.getNumerador();
        int Den = Multiplicación.getDenominador();

        Fraction c = new Fraction();

        c.Numerador = Numerador * Num;
        c.Denominador = Denominador * Den;
        return c;
    }

    public Fraction División(Fraction División) {
        int Num = División.getNumerador();
        int Den = División.getDenominador();

        Fraction c = new Fraction();

        c.Numerador = Numerador * Den;
        c.Denominador = Denominador * Num;
        return c;
    }

    public String ImpresiónFraction() {
        String Text = Numerador + "/" + Denominador;
        return Text;
    }

    public Float ImpresiónFloat() {
        Float Float = new Float(Numerador);
        Float Numero = Float.floatValue() / Denominador;
        return Numero;
    }

}
```

and this class for printing:

```
package fracciones;

public class FraccionCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fraction Una = new Fraction(1, 2);
        Fraction Dos = new Fraction(8, 16);

        System.out.println(Una.Resta(Dos));

        System.out.println(Una.ImpresiónFloat());

    }

}
```

Comment: I think this is happening because you are printing the object and not the values of the object. try printing object.Numerator and Denominator.

Comment: That's the object hashcode you are seeing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to override and define `toString()` yourself in your `Fraction` class if you want to print an object - otherwise you'll just print the object hashcode.

For example, the following might be something like what you want:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Fraction [" + Numerador + "/" + Denominador + "]";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Fraction` needs to implement the `toString()` method, as it is currently using [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) which returns:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Example implementation:

```
class Fraction
{
    @Override public String toString()
    {
        return Numerador + "/" + Denominador;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add this method in `Fraction` class

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Numerador: "+Numerador+", "+"Denominador: "+Denominador;
    }
```

PS: Use **camel case** while writing variable name and method name and use **pascal case** while writing class name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method in your class. `System.out.println()` uses that to get a textual representation of your objects.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing out the Reference to a Object. If you want to get the actual integer value, you have to provide getter methods or you are making the variables public and print them out directly via Una.Num and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this

```
System.out.println(Una.Resta(Dos).getNumerador() + Una.Resta(Dos).getDenominador());
```

Answer (score 1):

Una.Resta() => Return an object of class Fraction.
System.out.println => need a string to print. So it must cast the object to string by call toString() method of Object class. So you must implement this method in Fraction class to format the string you want to print out.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods return a type Fraction, this will need to implement the toString() method which yenables controling the string representation of an object.

Alternatively you can change the methods to have a return value of type string.